# Yii Errors 'Optmize cannot be blank!'

Tags: php, yii2

so I'm getting this error when I run the class:

```
<?php

/**
 * @link http://www.yiiframework.com/
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2008 Yii Software LLC
 * @license http://www.yiiframework.com/license/
 */

namespace app\commands;

use app\components\IFoodAPI;
use app\models\User;
use app\helper\RequestRideHelper;
use yii\console\Controller;
use yii\db\Query;

/**
 * This command echoes the first argument that you have entered.
 *
 * This command is provided as an example for you to learn how to create console commands.
 *
 * @author Qiang Xue <qiang.xue@gmail.com>
 * @since 2.0
 */
class IFoodApiController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * This command echoes what you have entered as the message.
     * @param string $message the message to be echoed.
     */

    public function actionIndex($message = 'hello world')
    {
        $ifoodApi = new IFoodAPI();

        $eventList = $ifoodApi->request(
            'GET',
            '/order/v1.0/events:polling',
            [
                'types' => 'PLC,REC,CFM',
                'groups' => 'ORDER_STATUS,DELIVERY'
            ]
        );

        if (is_array($eventList)) {
            $ridesList = [];

            foreach ($eventList as $eventData) {
                // Ask client order details
                $orderData = $ifoodApi->request(
                    'GET',
                    sprintf('/order/v1.0/orders/%s', $eventData['orderId'])
                );

                if (isset($orderData['delivery']['deliveryAddress']['formattedAddress'])) {
                    $ifoodMerchantId = $eventData['merchantId'];
                    // Query database for merchantID client match.
                    $query = new Query();
                    $rows = $query
                        ->select(['*'])
                        ->from('business')
                        ->where(['merchant_id' => $ifoodMerchantId])
                        ->limit(1)
                        ->all();

                    if (!empty($rows)) {
                        $businessData = $rows[0];
                        $businessId = $businessData['user_id'] ?? null;

                        if (!isset($ridesList[$businessId])) {
                            $ridesList[$businessId] = [];
                        }

                        $ridesList[$businessId][] = [
                            'originAddress' => $businessData['address'],
                            'origin_latitude' => $businessData['latitude'],
                            'origin_longitude' => $businessData['longitude'],
                            'origin_note' => $businessData['addressNote'],
                            'destinationAddress' => sprintf('%s', $orderData['delivery']['deliveryAddress']['formattedAddress']),
                            'destination_latitude' => $orderData['delivery']['deliveryAddress']['coordinates']['latitude'],
                            'destination_longitude' => $orderData['delivery']['deliveryAddress']['coordinates']['longitude'],
                            'destination_note' => [],
                            'external_id' => $orderData['displayId'],
                            'date' => $orderData['createdAt'],
                            'measures_id' => [],
                            'note' => [],
                            //                            'receiver_phone' => $orderData['customer']['phone']['number'],
                            'receiver_phone' => '(79) 99153-1519',
                            'receiver_name' => $orderData['customer']['name'],
                            'receiver_intermediate' => $orderData['customer']['name'],
                            'food' => true,
                            'is_food' => 1,
                            'volume' => [
                                'length' => 0.25,
                                'height' => 0.25,
                                'width' => 0.25,
                                'weight' => 0.25,
                            ],
                            'type_of_content' => 1,
                            'num_volumes' => 1,
                            'vehicle_type' => 0,
                            'type' => 0,
                        ];
                    }
                }
            }

            // iFood API orders confirmation
            $ifoodApi->request('POST', '/order/v1.0/events/acknowledgment', $eventList);

            foreach ($ridesList as $businessId => $rideListFromMerchant) {

                $requestForm = new \stdClass();
                $requestForm->rides = $rideListFromMerchant;
                $requestForm->optimize = false;

                $user = User::findIdentity($businessId);

                var_dump($response = (new RequestRideHelper())->requestRide($requestForm, $user));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, the requestRide method is returning an error:

```
object(app\models\Errors)#154 (7) {
  ["errors"]=>
  array(1) {  
    [0]=>
    string(25) "Optimize cannot be blank."
  }
  ["_errors":"yii\base\Model":private]=>
  NULL
  ["_validators":"yii\base\Model":private]=>
  NULL
  ["_scenario":"yii\base\Model":private]=>
  string(7) "default"
  ["_events":"yii\base\Component":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_eventWildcards":"yii\base\Component":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_behaviors":"yii\base\Component":private]=>
  NULL
}
```

What I don't understand is why the parameter was not sent in the request body. Can anyone help me with this one?

I tried to change the $requestForm from array to object, so in this way the request body will match the JSON correct params.

Comment: I think you need to show the `requestRide()` function.

Answer (score 0):

@Edgar Can try below code ?

```
foreach ($ridesList as $businessId => $rideListFromMerchant) {

$requestForm = new \stdClass();
$requestForm->rides = $rideListFromMerchant;
$requestForm->optimize = 0;  // 1=true and 0=false

$user = User::findIdentity($businessId);

var_dump($response = (new RequestRideHelper())->requestRide($requestForm, $user));
```

}